# Why isn't AF_INET working with SOCK_STREAM?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock2

I'm just starting out on gaining a better understanding of socket programming, and I'm trying to build a simple program that can send and receive messages. I've run into an issue with binding a socket to an address to use it. Here is what I have-

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool devbuild = true;

    WSADATA mainSdata;
    SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    sockaddr tobind;
    tobind.sa_family = AF_INET;
    char stringaddr[] = "192.168.1.1";
    inet_pton(AF_INET,stringaddr,&tobind);


    //initiating Windows Socket API (WSA)
    if (WSAStartup(2.2, &mainSdata) == 0)
    {
        if (devbuild == true)
        {
            printf("WSA successfully started...\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("WSA failed to set up, press [ENTER] to exit...\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    //instantiating the socket
    sock = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        if (devbuild == true)
        {
            printf("Socket successfully created...\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket failed to set up, press [ENTER] to exit...\n");
        pause();
        return 2;
    }

    //binding the socket
    if (bind(sock, &tobind, sizeof(tobind)) == 0)
    {
        if (devbuild == true)
        {
            printf("Socket successfully bound...\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket failed to bind, press [ENTER] to exit...\n");
        printf("Last WSA error was: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 3;
    }


    pause();


    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting a return of 3, with WSA error code **10047**

*10047 - WSAEAFNOSUPPORT
Address family not supported by protocol family.
An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. All sockets are created with an associated address family (that is, AF_INET for Internet Protocols) and a generic protocol type (that is, SOCK_STREAM). This error is returned if an incorrect protocol is explicitly requested in the socket call, or if an address of the wrong family is used for a socket, for example, in sendto.*

This doesn't make sense, because I am only using SOCK_STREAM and AF_INET, which support one another.

Comment: bind is supposed to take the full address of the local endpoint, which consists of IP and port. You are not giving a port and you mess up when writing the IP part into sockaddr. Please look up the documentation for more details. Apart from that better not only show which error you get but also where you get it.

Comment: I only know the original BSD socket API, not the Windows-isms larded on top, but using `WSASocket` together with `bind` looks fishy, and so does your use of `sockaddr` instead of `sockaddr_in`.

Comment: @zwol: `bind()` works just fine with `WSASocket()`. The problem is the `sockaddr` misuse.

Comment: On a side note, `WSAStartup(2.2, ...)` needs to be `WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), ...)` instead. A floating pointer number cannot be passed to `WSAStartup()`, it expects a `WORD` instead, where the major version is in the low byte and the minor version is in the high byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one problem (possibly not the only problem, but this is what jumps out at me) is in this line:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET,stringaddr,&tobind);
```

The problem is that you are passing `&tobind` as the final argument, and `tobind` is a `sockaddr`, but `inet_pton()` expects its third argument to point to a `struct in_addr` instead when using `AF_INET` (the fact that `inet_pton()` takes a void-pointer rather than a typed pointer for its third argument makes this kind of mistake really easy to make).

So what you should be doing instead is (note added error checking also):

```
if (inet_pton(AF_INET,stringaddr,&tobind.sin_addr) != 1)
   printf("inet_pton() failed!\n");
```

Also, you need to make `tobind` be of type `struct sockaddr_in` rather than just a `sockaddr`, and also you need to zero out the struct before using it:

```
struct sockaddr_in tobind;
memset(&tobind, 0, sizeof(tobind));   // make sure the uninitialized fields are all zero
tobind.sa_family = AF_INET;
[...]
```